# Difference between matrix multiplication and tensor contraction

Tags: math, matrix, tensorflow

When I look into the source code of Tensorflow, I found contract op is used in a lot of places.
However, I don't understand what's the different between the contraction and multiplication.
Can someone help explain this?

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication is a special case of tensor contraction (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction#Contraction_of_a_pair_of_tensors)). So in theory, you do not need to have a special matrix multiplication operation when you have tensor contraction implemented.

You may want to implement a special op for performance purposes though. And actually, looking at [tensorflow's operator implementations](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/fe589d9e7caea582beed160ad47e55f537a8403e/tensorflow/core/kernels), I don't see that `matmul` relies on tensor contraction. It definitely has its own implementation.